# Fast game player file saving?

Tags: java, save

I am making a multiplayer game in java, and it has clients that connect to the main server. I'm currently saving the players game in JSON format, with the file name equaling the players name. I was wondering if there is a better way that I should be doing it.

I need to store arrays, booleans, integers, and strings.

The file will be saved to whenever the player changes something in the game, such as pickup up an item.

Comment: You need to find out what the bottleneck is. Is it the data transmission over the net, the computation on the server or the DB / filesystem.

Comment: The server holds all the data of the player, not trusting the client. So the information is saved locally on the drive that the server is running off of. The game can hold around 1000+ players, so I need a good saving format to work with all that.

Comment: You should profile it, but my guess is that file I/O is the bottleneck. => Store in binary format (maybe with a bit compression  [be careful not to waste too much CPU power on compress/extract]) to reduce the amount of data to be written to file. Caching for often needed data would also be helpful. Maybe you can even hold the data of the players in the RAM (or at least that part of the player data that are needed often)

Comment: For specific suggestions of what and how to store, we need to know more details about the data you want to store.

Comment: The players have skills, and an inventory, bank, health etc, so they need to be stored on the drive and cannot be stored on RAM. JSON seems to be working good, but i'm not sure how it will perform with 1000 players on at a time constantly writing back and forth.

Comment: Is you manage to store the player data e.g in 50K Byte you could hold data for 2000 Player in 1GB RAM. You can store a lot of data in 50 KByte so I would not rule out the possibility of holding the data in the RAM.

Comment: Yes but if the server crashed wouldn't all that data be lost if it was stored in the RAM? I'd need to write it to some type of file to keep a physical backup. And the players accounts would all get reset? This is a game where players can buy things with real money, and build their character as time goes on.

Comment: You can asynchron write changed data to disk. This would eliminate latency and avoids the need of reading from disc.

Comment: What are your thoughts on saving the info to a MySql database? I'd like to eventually implement more than one game world, which would require more servers to be ran.